# How to read the contents from two files one by one using foreach loop?

Tags: tcl, expect

My TCL Script:

```
set a [open fruits.txt r]
set b [read $a]
foreach c $b {
    puts  "Fruits : $c"

    set website [open website_name1.txt r]
    set each_one [read $website]
    foreach each $each_one {
        puts  "website name : $c"
    }
}
```

`fruits.txt` contents:

```
apple orange mango litchi banana
```

`website_name1.txt` contents:

```
google.com yahoo.com metlife.com cisco.com span.com
```

Now if I run the above script, I am getting output as shown below:

```
D:\Desktop>tclsh statck_qns.tcl
Fruits : apple
website name : apple
website name : apple
website name : apple
website name : apple
website name : apple
Fruits : orange
website name : orange
website name : orange
website name : orange
website name : orange
website name : orange
Fruits : mango
website name : mango
website name : mango
website name : mango
website name : mango
website name : mango
Fruits : litchi
website name : litchi
website name : litchi
website name : litchi
website name : litchi
website name : litchi
Fruits : banana
website name : banana
website name : banana
website name : banana
website name : banana
website name : banana

D:\Desktop>
```

But I trying to get output as shown below:

```
Fruits : apple
website name : google.com 
Fruits : orange
website name : yahoo.com
Fruits : mango 
website name : metlife.com 
Fruits : litchi
website name : cisco.com 
Fruits : banana
website name : span.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. You are using `$c` in the second loop while it should be `$each`. Also, if you want to put the website name only once, you need to get a loop that loops through both lists at the same time.

```
set a [open fruits.txt r]
set b [read $a]

set website [open website_name1.txt r]
set each_one [read $website]

foreach c $b each $each_one {
  puts  "Fruits : $c"
  puts  "website name : $each"
}

close $a
close $website
```

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/OAYMh79J)

You can loop through two lists (or more) with `foreach` with the above format, i.e.:

```
foreach var1 list1 var2 list2 ... varn listn {
  # code here
}
```

If the number of elements are not the same in the lists, then you will start get empty strings in the variable name of the list with the shorter number of elements.

Comment: be aware that this approach loops over the **words** in the files, not the **lines**. If you have "granny smith apple" in fruits.txt, your output will probably not be what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Can also read line-by-line with a while loop

```
set f_fruit [open fruits.txt r]
set f_web [open website_name1.txt r]
while {[gets $f_fruit fruit] != -1 && [gets $f_web website] != -1} {
    puts "Fruits: $fruit"
    puts "website name: $website"
}
close $f_fruit
close $f_web
```